# Building a dynamic select query using Spring Data Specification

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a select query with Spring Data Specification. The query in question is the following:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_tags WHERE tags IN ('GRADUATION', 'BIRTHDAY'));`

The user is supposed to provide a set of tags to be matched with the `IN` operator in the subquery, BIRTHDAY and GRADUATION are some examples. I've tried building my solution off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285371/18316696) answer but ran into some trouble.

```java
    public static Specification<Product> withTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
        return tags == null ?
                null :
                (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                    Subquery<Tags> subquery = query.subquery(Tags.class);

                    Root<Tags> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(Tags.class);
                    subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get("product_tags")
                        .get("product_id"));
                    subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.trim(subqueryRoot.get("product")
                        .get("id")).in(tags));

                    predicates.add(subqueryRoot.get("*").in(subquery));
                    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

                };
    }
```

The problem here is that I'm trying to create a subquery from `Tags` which is not registered as an entity but it is rather an enum. Thus, executing the code gives me an error (This is the only error I've encountered so far, please point out parts of the code that may potentially cause other errors).

```java
public enum Tags {

    BIRTHDAY("birthday"),
    GRADUATION("graduation"),
    GET_WELL_SOON("get well soon"),
    RIBBON("ribbon"),
    WRAPPING_PAPER("wrapping paper");

    final String tagName;

    private Tags(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this will help, but in the `Product` class there is a field `tags` denoted with `@ElementCollection`. Spring automatically creates a table named 'product_tags' with this, and the subquery selects from this table.

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Tags> tags;
```

If possible, I would like to translate this query instead of the first one

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_tags WHERE tags = ANY(ARRAY['GRADUATION', 'GET_WELL_SOON']));`

**UPDATE**

I have edited my code

```java
    public static Specification<Product> withTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
        return tags == null ?
                null :
                (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
            Root<Product> subroot = subquery.from(Product.class);

            subquery.select(subroot.get("id").get("tags"));

            subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.trim(subroot.join("tags")
                .get("id")).in(tags));

            predicates.add(root.get("id").in(subquery));

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
```

But now I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.id] of basic type
```

For reference, my tables are defined as such

product:

```
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | bigint                 |           | not null |
 category    | character varying(255) |           |          |
 date_added  | date                   |           |          |
 description | character varying(255) |           |          |
 name        | character varying(255) |           |          |
 price       | double precision       |           | not null |
```

product_tags:

```
   Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 product_id | bigint                 |           | not null |
 tags       | character varying(255) |           |          |
```

Comment: H-m-m... perhaps you may try to use Set<String> built from Tags getTagName()?

Comment: That's a good alternative but I would prefer using Tags if possible. And while we're on the topic of Sets, is it possible for a url parameter to accept a collection of objects? I'm getting this new error: `Parameter value [] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)];`

Comment: If I were to use a Set of Strings, how would you suggest I build the query?

Comment: maybe something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512109/set-array-of-parameters-to-hibernate-query-language

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Specification<Product> withTags(Set<Tags> tags) {
        return tags.isEmpty() ?
                null:
                (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                    Subquery<Tags> subquery = query.subquery(Tags.class);
                    Root<Product> subroot = subquery.from(Product.class);

                    subquery.select(subroot.get("id")).where(subroot.join("tags").in(tags));
                    Predicate predicate = root.get("id").in(subquery);

                    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicate);
        };
```

I seemed to have found an answer. `Tags.class` works apparently, and from there I just had to tweak my query to be a join select. Not what I initially hoped to accomplish, but it works.